# Create overlay with scroll enabled in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uiview, overlay, layer

I have a view with a UICollectionView (with scroll enabled).

I would like that, when I click on a button, there is a black overlay shown behind a menu.It would be better with a picture:

[image]

The problem is that this overlay is not covering all the background when I scroll down.

When the scroll is up, it's perfect, but when scroll down we can see the limit of the subview.

This is my code:

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
      let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
overlay = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
      overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.3)
      overlay.layer.zPosition = 1

// AND WHEN THE BUTTON IS PRESSED
// self.collectionView.addSubview(overlay)``
```

How could I correct this problem ?

Comment: what are those `width` and `height` vars ?

Comment: I would rather add the overlay to superview in order to disable scrolling at all. Or you can use the `contentSize` property for setting right width and height of overlay view.

Comment: Excuse me, I edited my post for the width and height

Comment: Your width and height constants are the same.